# What happens to reputation if an upvoted answer is moved to another SE site?

Tags: support, questions, answers, migration, reputation

As per object: if a question which received some upvotes is moved to another SE site, what happens to the OP reputation?

Does her/his reputation on CV decreases, and the reputation on the other site increases? Or does the moved question start on the other site with 0 upvotes? In this case the OP rep on CV decreases, but her/his rep on the other site doesn't increase?

And what about comments? Are they moved together with the question or do they simply get lost?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What happens to reputation if an upvoted **answer** is moved to another SE site?

The answer is deleted in the source site and the reputation is revoked. Votes are migrated to the target site with their respective posts, and if the answer's author has an account there, it will receive the associated reputation.

> If a **question** which received some upvotes is moved to another SE site, what happens to the OP reputation?

Pretty much the same as above, except downvotes are cleared out, and that the question is left as a pathway for 30 days in the source site (reputation is only reversed after the question is deleted, i.e., after that 30 days).

> Does her/his reputation on CV decreases, and the reputation on the other site increases?

Yes, if questions do have upvotes (there can be exceptions like a heavily downvoted question, which would make reputation increase in the source site after deletion, but let's keep it simple).

> Or does the moved question start on the other site with 0 upvotes?

It starts in the target site with the amount of upvotes it had in the source site when migrated.

> And what about comments? Are they moved together with the question or do they simply get lost?

Yes, all comments on any post are moved/migrated together with their respective posts.

---

References in Stack Exchange Meta:

- [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work/10250#10250)
- [Do migrated questions migrate reputation and badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6378/do-migrated-questions-migrate-reputation-and-badges)
- [What happens to rep earned on posts that are later migrated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168754/what-happens-to-rep-earned-on-posts-that-are-later-migrated)

Comment: Interesting that downvotes are not migrated, only upvotes. I did not know that.

Comment: Whoops! I  wanted to ask about migrating questions, but I erroneously referred to answers in the question title. Thanks for answering about both :)